# How to change caption position right under image on mobile resolution - Fancybox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

By default fancybox 3 caption is right under the image on pc/tablet device BUT on mobile (350x800) caption is not under the image its on the bottom of tha page .

How can i make caption right under the image on mobile device ?

After looking an hour i did not found the way to do it

Here is the example of the image just turn on mobile (350x800) [Fancybox 3 Image](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#images-3)

I was trying beforeShow function to get width/height of fancybox-content and then set posittion of caption but beforeShow working only when you swipe next/prev image not on first open

```
        $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({

          beforeShow: function() {
            console.log($('.fancybox-content').width());
          },

        });
```

Log

```
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this done for me

```
            afterLoad: function(instance, current) {
              var width = $('#fancybox-content').context.activeElement.clientWidth;
              var height = $(window).height();
              var calHeight = (height - width ) / 3

              if (img < 600) {
                $('.fancybox-caption.fancybox-caption--separate').css('bottom', ''+calHeight+'px');
              }
            },
```